# list available parameters of variable

Tags: elementcriteriamodel

Is there a way to print all of the available parameters/handles when I set a variable?

For example if I put `{% set orders = craft.commerce.orders.find() %}` is there a way to list out the available parameters/handles depending on what I set, without having to go to the docs? So a way of checking that my code is right from the templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a purely Twig/template solution, then your best bet would be to either enable devMode and use Twig's [`dump()`](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/dump.html) method or install something like the Craft [Kint](https://github.com/mildlygeeky/craft_kint) plugin.

Keep in mind that both of them are going to give you much more information than just attributes available on a model (like the array of [OrderModel](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/order-model)'s your example is going to return), but that info will be included.